# Scala + Gradle + AndroidStudio 0.8.+

Tags: android, scala, gradle, android-studio

Is it still impossible to write Android applications with Scala/Gradle/AndroidStudio pack?
I couldn't find anything relevant on the web.

Links would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [scala-on-android mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-on-android/0y1VQ8t4Ojg) this plugin should work at least for the gradle/android/scala part (and IDEA instead of AndroidStudio): [gradle-android-scala-plugin](https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin).